# Nodejs is ot returning mysql data from my insert function in a class module

Tags: node.js

```
    var mysql = require('mysql')
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 200,
    host            : 'localhost',
    user            : 'root',
    password        : '',
    database        : 'taxi'
});
class Pool{
    check(){
        pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
            if(err){
                console.log(err.sqlMessage)
            }else{
                console.log("connected")
                connection.release()
            }
            
        })
   
    }

    async insert(table,column,data, callback){
        pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
            if(err){
                console.log(err.sqlMessage)
            }else{
               var sql = "Insert Into " + table + "("+column+") VALUES ("+data+") "
               connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
                   connection.release()
                   if(err){
                       callback(err.sqlMessage)
                   }else{
                       return(result)
                   }
               })
            }
            
        })
    }
}

module.exports = Pool
```

> Can not able to return the data from insert function, it is returning undefined.
> I want to create a mysql class module that can be called from other classes and insert, fetch and update data with functions in the database class file.

Comment: You're not actually returning anything from the `insert` function. You're only returning from the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare `insert` function as `async` you should return `Promise` with a result and don't use `callback`:

```js
 async insert(table,column,data){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
            if(err){
                console.log(err.sqlMessage)
                reject(err)
            }else{
               var sql = "Insert Into " + table + "("+column+") VALUES ("+data+") "
               connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
                   connection.release()
                   if(err){
                       reject(err)
                   }else{
                       resolve(result)
                   }
               })
            }
            
        })
      });
    }
```